# Disk Management sees the disk and partitions - change drive letter greyed out?

Tags: hard-drive, diskmanagement

Environment:

From: Windows XP-Pro x64

To: Windows 10 Pro

A user "left" the company and we found a Win XP-Pro x64 workstation under his desk - but no user/password for login.

I've taken the SATA drives (no RAID - JBOD) out of the XP box and put them into a Win 10 box to find out what's on them.  But I can't access the 2nd disk.

Running Disk Management on Win 10 box:

- XP boot disk is good - see all partitions and able to assign drive letters.
- XP second disk - see all partitions, but unable to access any of them.

  - [Change Drive Letter] is greyed out for all three partitions on 2nd disk.

[image: Disk Management screen shot]

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Try in Linux, maybe it's not NTFS (or it's encrypted).

Comment: Thanks @Sven, but Windows allows you to change drive letters on any partition except the OS partition - (even if encrypted).  And Linux will still be accessing the disk with NTFS driver - so I don't see anything there that would help - (is there?).  FYI: We are a Windows only shop - and the C: drive from his workstation is a Windows bootable disk.

Comment: Windows can't read Linux partitions (or better: Linux file systems) and don't allow you to assign drive letters to them. What you see there (Healthy, Primary partition, no file system type like e.g. NTFS) is exactly what Windows show you if you connect a Linux disk.